# set valid constraint for embedded entity only if flag in embedded object property is set

Tags: php, symfony, validation, constraints

I am using symfony3.4.
Now i have a form presented by a data-class which uses several child entities as property:

```
contact {
   protected $address;
   protected $user;
   protected $message;
}
```

The address entity includes a field "address->validate" which can be set by the user in the frontend. The requirement now is, that address only should be validated, if the user checks the field "address->validatable".

```
address {
   private $street;
   //[...]
   private $validatable; //bool

   public function isValidatable(){...}
}
```

Normally, I would use a callback-constraint, to check the field. But since the callback function is static, all the examples only show callbacks with one single field-property and ExecutionContextInterface does not allow me, to add constraints afterwards, I don't know how to implement it.

Can anybody tell me how to solve this case?

EDIT:
Thanks to Marc I solved it this way:
I have a form-type-class called "ContactGeneralType". In this class I add the group like described on https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/form/data_based_validation.html:

```
    /**
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults($this->addDefaults([
        'data_class' => ContactGeneral::class,
        'cascade_validation' => true,
    ]));

    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'validation_groups' => function (FormInterface $form) {
            $data = $form->getData();
            if ($data->getAddress()->isValidatable()) {
                return ['User', 'Address'];
            } else {
                return ['User'];
            }
        },
    ]);
}
```

That does all the trick. If you have more address-validation-groups (e.g. if you validate different countries), you already can inject your service in the form-type-class and set the group-name dynamically, too:

```
            if ($data->getAddress()->isValidatable()) {
                return ['User', $this->locationManager>getGroupName()];
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using callback, try creating custom validator that is explained here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html. You get your Object inside of validator and you can check if field is checked or w/e and validate based on that.

EDIT:

Maybe changing the validation group on form submit is better solution as described here https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_based_validation.html

Comment: Hi Mark and thank you for your answer, but how can I then add the constraints for the sub-entity-properties?

Comment: @j0nnybrav0 so I did not get your whole problem at first but now I understand, maybe go with custom validation groups and add them to your form as described here https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_based_validation.html

Comment: Hi Mark and thank you very much, this solved all my problems. Due to your hint, i always thought, I can only set ONE group for validation, till I found the little the sentence "To tell the validator to use a specific group, pass one or more group names as the third argument to the validate() method" on https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/validation/groups.html.